# CSS: How to position image across two columns, with wrap text? (img included for reference)

Tags: html, css, sass, col

I have an article that I am turning into html. The article has two columns, and there is an image that spills over from one column into another, as seen in this screen shot of the article:

[image]

I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to position this image. If I use position: absolute, it just sits on top of the text. Any suggestions on how I might figure this out?

Comment: sounds a bit like this could be a job for exclusions once they are supported. https://css-tricks.com/exclusions-will-hopefully-be-like-more-powerful-grid-friendly-floats/ 
With current technologies you could try using shapes on the left column but this would then be independent of the image and would need to be adjusted if the image changes. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can try this one.

```css
.image1 img {
  width: 678px;
  height: 350px;
  margin-left: -140px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapit {
  width: 75%;
  text-align: justify;
}

@media(max-width:991px) {
  .wrapit {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .image1 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <h1>Two colum with image</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <br>

        <div class="wrapit">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</div>

        when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
        the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <div class="image1"><img src="http://icrs.org.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/pojo-placeholder-2-2.png"></div>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>

    </div>




</body>

</html>
```